# Mongoose updateMany by id using Node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

is it possible to update array of object by id? ex.:

This is my array:

```
[
  {
        "_id": "5fdb614d686e671eb834a409",
        "order": 1,
        "title": "first"
  },
  {
        "_id": "5fdb61c0686e671eb834a41e",
        "order": 2,
        "title": "second" 
  },
  {
        "_id": "5fdb61d6686e671eb834a424",
        "order": 3,
        "title": "last"
  }
]
```

and I would like to change only the order of each by ID. I am using Node and I tried to do like that:

```
router.post("/edit-order", auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const sections = await Section.updateMany(
      req.body.map((item) => {
        return { _id: item._id }, { $set: { order: item.order } };
      })
    );

    res.json(sections);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Something went wrong in /edit-order" });
  }
});
```

my request body is:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5fdb614d686e671eb834a409",
        "order": 2
    },
    {
        "_id": "5fdb61c0686e671eb834a41e",
        "order": 3
    },
    {
        "_id": "5fdb61d6686e671eb834a424",
        "order": 4
    }
]
```

but as a result, I got:

```
[
  {
        "_id": "5fdb614d686e671eb834a409",
        "order": 4,
        "title": "first"
  },
  {
        "_id": "5fdb61c0686e671eb834a41e",
        "order": 4,
        "title": "second" 
  },
  {
        "_id": "5fdb61d6686e671eb834a424",
        "order": 4,
        "title": "last"
  }
]
```

so, it change every order by the last value of request array. Any ideas how could I manage that. If you know any other solution feel free to share, all what I need is to change order only by id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since you have a different value of `order` for each item, you'll need to do a [bulkWrite](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/).

```js
router.post('/edit-order', auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const writeOperations = req.body.map((item) => {
      return {
        updateOne: {
          filter: { _id: item._id },
          update: { order: item.order }
        }
      };
    });

    await Section.bulkWrite(writeOperations);

    res.json(req.body);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Something went wrong in /edit-order' });
  }
});
```

If you had a single value of `order` to all the items, you could've used `updateMany` along with `$in`.

```js
router.post('/edit-order', auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const sectionsIds = req.body.map((item) => {
      return item._id;
    });
    const sections = await Section.updateMany(
      { _id: { $in: sectionsIds } },
      { order: 'A single value for all sections in body' }
    );

    res.json(sections);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Something went wrong in /edit-order' });
  }
});
```

Comment: bulkWrite worked great, but after some time it started to throw an error and I have no idea why. Now, even request body is good etc, I recieve status 500. Could it be something with "bulkWrite "? All other ports work great, so it is not MongoDB connection issues

Comment: If I use:  update: { $setOnInsert: { order: item.order } }, bulkWrite does not throw error, but it does not make any changes as well. It show matchedCount 3 but modifiedCount:0. Using $set does not work as well

Comment: I found a problem. I had an "11000 E11000 duplicate key error index" error. I dropped the database and all started to work.